# mysql join on same table with different ID's

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Table : datatable

```
    +----+-------+-------+
    | Id | Name  | Value |
    +----+-------+-------+
    | 50 | Eric  | 1200  |
    | 50 | Barb  | 1195  |
    | 50 | Joe   | 1180  |
    | 51 | Barb  |   6   |
    | 51 | Eric  |   3   |
    | 51 | Joe   |   5   |
    +----+-------+-------+
```

I want to this result

```
    +-------+---------+--------+
    | Name  | Value1  | Value2 |
    +-------+---------+--------+
    | Eric  |  1200   |   3    |
    | Barb  |  1195   |   6    |
    | joe   |  1180   |   5    |
    +-------+---------+--------+
```

I don't know how to merge this.

```
SELECT name, value from datatable WHERE Id=50 AS Value1 
JOIN datatable 
WHERE Id=51 AS  Value2 ON value1.Name = value2.Name ORDER BY value1.Value
```

and dont know how to call `value2`?

```
$row["??"]
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can do a `Group By` on `Name`.
- Now, you can utilize conditional Aggregation using [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) and [`Max()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) functions.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
  t.Name, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN t.Id = 50 THEN t.VALUE END) AS Value1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t.Id = 51 THEN t.VALUE END) AS Value2 
FROM datatable AS t
GROUP BY t.Name
```

Comment: it works but shows empty cells, i figured out in php -- if (Value1 != null) 
it is working but not the best way i think. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user2796291 if there is no value for id = 50 or 51, what do you want to show then ?

Comment: that code merge 50 and 51, its ok. but it list all other IDs. 41,42, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use table aliases

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.value AS Value1,t2.value AS Value2 from datatable t1 
JOIN datatable t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t1.Id=51 and t2.Id=50 
ORDER BY value1.Value
```

Comment: MySQL ERROR :
 #1052 - Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous